# How to make a calculation in a pandas daframe depending on a value of a certain column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe and I want to make a calculation depending on a condition, like below:

```
   count  prep  result
     0      10     100
    10      100    100
```

I wanto to create a new column `evaluated` that is:

```
if df['count']==0: 
    df['evaluated'] = df['result'] / df['prep']
else:
    df['evaluated'] = df['result'] / df['count']
```

**expected result is:**

```
   count  prep  result   evaluated
     0      10     100      10
    100     10     100      1
```

What's the best way to do it?  My real dataframe has 30k rows.

Comment: the provided example also shows a change in "prep", given your description I assume this is incorrect, please clarify otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) or [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['evaluated'] = df['result'].div(df['prep'].where(df['count'].eq(0), df['count']))
```

Or:

```
df['evaluated'] = df['result'].div(df['count'].mask(df['count'].eq(0), df['prep']))
```

Output (assuming there was an error in the provided input):

```
   count  prep  result  evaluated
0      0    10     100       10.0
1    100    10     100        1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) from `numpy` to do that:

```
df['evaluated'] = np.where(df['count'] == 0,
                           df['result'] / df['prep'],   # == 0
                           df['result'] / df['count'])  # != 0
```

Performance (not really significant) over 30k rows:

```
>>> %timeit df['result'].div(df['prep'].where(df['count'].eq(0), df['count']))
652 µs ± 12.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit df['result'].div(df['count'].mask(df['count'].eq(0), df['prep']))
638 µs ± 1.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit np.where(df['count'] == 0, df['result'] / df['prep'], df['result'] / df['count'])
462 µs ± 1.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```